# Angular 2, ASP.NET Core, WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, angular, http

How can i get data from httpPUT request?
Controller:

```
if (clientBalances.amount > currentAmount.amount)
        {
            return Content("Insufficient funds in your account");
        }
```

component:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.put(this.originUrl + '/api/ClientBalances/Out', JSON.stringify(balance), { headers: headers }).subscribe(result => {
        this.Message = result.json();
    });
```

But this return only "Response with status: 200 OK for URL:".
And how can i get my message?

Comment: Have you checked if the the value goes through via network?

Comment: Yes, I checked with the console

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.map()` part of the http method. You will also need to import `Http, Response` from `'@angular/http';`

```
public method(): void {
    let url: string = this.originUrl + '/api/ClientBalances/Out';
    this.http.put(url, balance)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
    });
}
```

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. Please mark the answer as correct then. Thank you